# PostgreSQL ilike with multiple matches in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am trying to retrieve multiple records from my DB with the following query:

```
User.where('name ilike ?','%thomas%')
```

this works fine. Now I want to retrieve multiple records at the same time and tried this (which seems to be syntactically incorrect):

```
User.where('name ilike any',['%thomas%','%james%','%martin%'])
```

What am I doing wrong?

So just to clarify: I want to retrieve all records that match one of the names, so its an OR statement I am looking for.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do it by

```
User.where('name ilike any ( array[?] )',['%thomas%','%james%','%martin%'])
```