# How to search an array column for multiple strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a column set up like this in my table

```
add_column :logs, :names, :string, array: true
add_index :logs, :names, using: :gin
```

I have this query to search the table via the names column to return records that contain robert

```
Logs.where("? = ANY (names)", 'robert')
```

I am curious on how to search the table for multiple names. Something like this, but the below query does not work

```
Logs.where("? = ANY (names)", ['robert', 'bob'])
```

I want it to function to something similar like this, where I pass in an array and returns all records that match

```
User.where(id: [1,2,3,4])
```

I need it as an OR statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.where(names: ['robert', 'bob'])

User.where("names IN (?) ", ['robert', 'bob'])
```

note: Its case sensitive

[This answer will also helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26272504/8333125)

Comment: I need the statement to be an OR statement so if name contains either robert or bob it should return it

Comment: also note the column is names and it is an array

Comment: @RobMason I have updated the answer. Can u please check it now..

Comment: error message: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information

Comment: @RobMason It works fine for me. can u please recheck it.

Answer (score 1):

```
# SQL Contains Operator
1) User.where("names @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", ['robert', 'bob'])


# Contains Operator
2) User.where.contains(names: ['robert', 'bob'])


# Overlap Operator
3) User.where.overlap(names: ['robert', 'bob'])
```

Comment: I need the statement to be an OR statement so if names contains either robert or bob it should return it